# Login With Yahoo (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, yahoo

I'am working on yahoo login. Previously it was working fine suddenly it stopped working.

Problem : fetchToken(withCallbackUrl: self.session.callbackUrl) method is returning nil.

Following is the code used:

```
    let session = YahooSession(consumerKey: yahooConsumerKey, andConsumerSecret: yahooConsumerSecretKey, andApplicationId: applicationID, andCallbackUrl: yahooCallbackUrl)



    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {() -> Void in
        self.session.resumeSession()

        let tokenAuthRequest = YOSAuthRequest(session: self.session)
        let newRequestToken: YOSRequestToken? = tokenAuthRequest?.fetchToken(withCallbackUrl: self.session.callbackUrl)

        if newRequestToken != nil && newRequestToken?.key != nil && newRequestToken?.secret != nil {
            self.session.requestToken = newRequestToken
            self.session.save()
            guard let authUrl = tokenAuthRequest?.authUrl(for: self.session.requestToken) else {return}
            if self.mobileWebAuthorization {
                let mobileWebLogin = "https://login.yahoo.com/m?&.src=oauth&.lang=en-us&.intl=us&.done="
                self.authorizationUrl = URL(string: "\(mobileWebLogin)\(authUrl)")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                let request = URLRequest(url: self.authorizationUrl!)
                self.webView?.loadRequest(request)
                self.view.showIndicator()
            })
        } else {
            print("Error, no request token returned. Check your consumer key and secret.")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Are you able to get token in Postman?

Comment: It is an SDK How can we get it by postman.